# List Postgres materialized views the current user has select grant

Tags: postgresql, materialized-view

With `select matviewname from pg_matviews` I get all materialized views in the database. How can I filter the result to get only those the current user has select grant (= read permission) on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function [`has_table_privilege()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-ACCESS-TABLE) to check that:

```
select mv.*
from pg_catalog.pg_matviews mv
where has_table_privilege(format('%I.%I', mv.schemaname, mv.matviewname), 'select')
```

The version with two parameters checks this for the current user. Alternatively you can use the version with three parameters and pass the user name explicitly.